# Disable a rule from ProGuard configuration of a library

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, proguard, android-proguard

A project I'm working on contains a lot of external dependencies on 3rd party libraries. While analyzing compiled apk I found out that a package within the app that is supposed to be obfuscated remains clean. When I dived deeper I figured out that merged ProGuard configuration contains a rule breaking obfuscation logic.

None of the project's ProGuard configurations contain this rule. So I assume that it was gotten from one of the dependencies and merged to final configuration.

I look through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34204827/ignore-proguard-configuration-of-an-external-library) but it seems that the answer is no longer valid for Android Plugin for Gradle 3.0.1 that I'm using because `build/intermediates/exploded-aar` folder no longer contains any ProGuard configurations.

So I'm wondering:

- Is there a way to find what library causes the problem?
- Is it still possible to disable a rule from consumer proguard file?